# Update UI on Data change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, web-applications

(I mostly work with Vue.js so many examples will relate to it)

I am learning to build web apps and the most time-consuming thing is the synchronization of the UI components and the data that they should represent, that is, coherence between what is shown to the user and what is stored in memory (locally).

For instance, suppose I have the following component tree:

```
<body>
    <form/>
    <task-bar/>
    <component-1>
    <component-2>
</body>
```

Here the parent component is body, and it has four childs, namely form, task-bar, component-1 and component-2.

We have a list of objects, for example:

```
[
{
   id: 1,
   title: "X"
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Y"
}
]
```

Taskbar lists the component title.

Component-1 shows the object selected in Component-2 via a radio button.

Now, in form I want to add an object to the list or edit/delete the selected component in Component-2.

In Vue.js I would pass the list from parent body to its child components, however, parent and siblings are not reactive by default to the data of child and siblings. Therefore a change on the list by a sibling creates an incoherent state between all components.

I read two ways to solve it, first is using events, child does something and notifies (This is what I used to do back in Java Swing, an observer pattern), this however turn to be extremely cumbersome after some events, moreover, its hard to debug and you might repeat events code in different components.

The second way is using a global state, such as Flux pattern implemented in Vuex. This however couples all components to the Vuex of a the specific project and makes it less portable.

My question is, are these the two unique ways to do things? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do one of the following:

- use a variable *like* it was a global state. You have an example of this in Vue's doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html
- in your component, use $parent.doSomething(), where doSomething() is a method of your parent component.

But personally, I like vuex :)